# Specify multiple different policy files when invoking execution of an application in Java

Tags: java, java-8, securitymanager

In the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html) it says it is also possible to specify an additional or a different policy file when invoking execution of an application. This can be done via the **"-Djava.security.policy"** command line argument, which sets the value of the **java.security.policy** property. For example, if you use,

```
java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=someURL SomeApp
```

With this we can specify an additional policy file to consider if `policy.allowSystemProperty` is set to **true**. Is it possible to use and set multiple policy files this way.

ie. ex :

```
java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=someURL -Djava.security.policy=someSecondURL SomeApp
```

Or is there any other way to do that ?

Comment: As noted in the linked documentation, that's only possible by setting the `policy.url.n` properties in `<JRE/JDK>/lib/security/java.security`. Alternatively you could try extending `java.security.Policy` (since the default `sun.security.provider.PolicyFile` implementation is unfortunately non-standard).